# Time tick in JSP without reloading the page

Tags: jsp

I know it is possible to change time variable using JavaScript or something else, but I try to do it using JSP-s, without reloading the whole page.

To be more specific my code is the following:

```
<% 
    for(int second = 0; second < 60; i++)
    {
        out.print(second);
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
        catch(InterruptedException e) { return; }       
    }

%>
```

...and it doesn't tick and show the time passed after every second. Instead, only after 60 seconds it shows that the time is over. **So is it possible to show the 'second' variable after every second in JSP or can I use sockets to accomplish this?** Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP code is executed server-side. So the JSP you implement in your question will take 1 minute to render and then print all the seconds at once. You'll need to utilize Javascript to dynamically update your page once it's loaded by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

No.

JSP runs on the server and sends the output to the browser.

There is no way to get the output from JSP to change without either:

- Making a new HTTP request to the server and getting a new response *or*
- Moving the logic that updates the content to client-side JavaScript (where you get to run code in the browser and have access to the DOM).